# Is this a right and effcient way of checking AND in a for loop

Tags: c#, algorithm

Just saw this at work in a code review and was wondering if this style of coding - for loop, doing && like that, seems fine to you or is there a better way of doing the same?

```
for (int j = 1; j <= ETtop; j++)
{ 
    // Check everything.
    int k = ET[j].PriIdx;
    for (int z = 1; z <= ET[k].ArgTop; z++ )
    {
        // Check to make sure every Argument in the equation is valid.
        // If it's a calc this is only true if it's been evaluated.
        ready = ready && ET[k].Arg[z].Valid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep seems ok to me.  Perhaps minor changes might be changing j, z and k to an actual meaning if relevant.

Comment: Only thing you could do is change to `ready &= ET[k].Arg[z].Valid`, but that might lower readability for some. I'd improve the variable names though, but that's another topic. :)

Answer (score 5):

Currently, once you get `ready` to be false, all other checks after that will fail (as `false && condition2` will always be false).

Why not just break out of the inner for loop when `ET[k].Arg[z].Valid` is false?  If `ready` is needed, you may keep the assignment line, but break when it's false.

Comment: somewhere above the code that I posted there are some areas that ready can be set to True...so in this case does your answer still correct?

Comment: Nope.  If `ready` can be changed back to true, then the && condition is probably necessary.  The optimization may be that you could break out earlier depending on when you check things . . .

Comment: @ernie : As this is code review, it would be appreciated if you posted your rewritten version of the code.

Comment: @yekAdami I should clarify, if `ready` can be changed in the inner for-loop, then the code is likely fine.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would rewrite your code to use collections instead of indexers and `top` properties. That way, you could use `foreach` instead of `for`, or, even better, LINQ:

```
ready = ET.All(e => e.Arg.All(arg => arg.Valid))
```

or:

```
ready = (from e in ER
         from arg in e.Arg
         select arg.Valid)
       .All();
```

This most likely won't make your code faster (although it does use short-circuit evaluation), but it will make it more readable, IMHO.

Comment: Combining this answer with ernie's, perhaps it could instead be ready = !ET.Any(e => e.Arg.Any(arg => !arg.Valid)).

Comment: @DanLyons I think that only makes things more complicated for no benefit.